# gzipped js/css not understood by browser. transfer-encoding issue?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, gzip

- I have a stylesheet living in /static/styles/min.css
- When headers allow, I rewrite it to /static/styles/min.css.gz (a pre-compressed file)
- When I request the min.css file using curl+GET, I get back the compressed contents.
- When I request the actual page in the browser, none of the CSS is applied.
- If I turn off the re-writing, the CSS is applied fine, so it is a problem with the gzipped content.
- Response headers include: "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary", "Content-Type: application/x-gzip", "Content-Length: 61021"

This is what's in my VirtualHost file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css$ $1\.css\.gz [L,T=text/css]
<FilesMatch .*\.css\.gz>
    ForceType text/css
    Header unset Content-Transfer-Encoding
    Header append Content-Encoding gzip
    Header append Content-Type text/css
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You probably want Header set not header append (it's quite likely you're sending multiple content-type headers). Doesn't mod_deflate cache the things that it compresses? is it really worth pre-zipping these files (I dunno)? Can't resist: *cough* nginx. *cough* faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Header set doesn't fix it. I don't think mod_deflate does cache. Regardless, I want to avoid putting that load on apache. Our build system pre-compresses these files so it's really no extra overhead from a dev perspective. Nginx is faster, but I am the only dev/admin on this large site, and I have no experience with it and not enough bandwidth to pick up anything new right now.

Answer (score 2):

Requesting the file foo.css.gz, using the following rules

```
<FilesMatch "\.css\.gz$">
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header set Content-Type "text/css; charset=utf-8"
</FilesMatch>
```

Results in the following headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=2592000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:71
Content-Type:text/css; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 08 Feb 2012 21:01:34 GMT 
Expires:Fri, 09 Mar 2012 21:01:34 GMT 
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Sun, 05 Feb 2012 21:53:14 GMT 
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e DAV/2 PHP/5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch
```

Which are the same headers (slightly different content-length) as requesting foo.css and letting mod_deflate do its thing (using the standard .htaccess file from [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)).

You may find this repo useful: https://github.com/AD7six/h5bp-server-check :)

Comment: I tried adding that header, and no, it is not showing in the response headers, so something is wrong. I avoided mentioning this here because I didn't want to confuse things further, but these minified files are living on another server, which I'm reverse proxying to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185769/mod-rewrite-not-working-with-reverse-proxy-in-vhost

Comment: Unfortunately, the cdn doesn't allow us to specify which headers we require. For this reason I am manually setting caching headers for images that live on the cdn, and those headers DO get set. Seems like something about the rewrite or gzip is causing all these issues. Oh well. I guess I will use deflate for now. Not ideal, but at least it works.